# MVC6 app VSO build and deployment to Azure fails

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I'm having trouble deploying my first MVC6 app to Azure from Visual Studio online. I've created a build definition that creates a deployment package and an "Azure app service deploy" task to deploy that package. The deployment task reports this error:

```
Failed to deploy App Service.
Error: (2/17/2017 9:09:59 AM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
Error: Source (sitemanifest) and destination (contentPath) are not compatible for the given operation.
Error count: 1.
Successfully updated deployment History at https://xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/deployments/5121487351399775
Error: C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe failed with return code: 4294967295
```

I can build an deploy the package from within Visual Studio. I have built and deployed a handful of MVC5 apps successfully with the same technique. I've never had a problem, so I'm not sure where to start figuring this out. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: So I believe this has something to do with the -dest:contentPath parameter passed to msdeploy. With my previous working builds, this value is set to "auto". But with the non-working build, it's set to "'<sitename>'". Where does this value come from?

Comment: Can you share your build definition settings？

Comment: I have a Build solution task with the arguments:  /t:PackagePublish /p:PublishProfile=Package /p:SkipInvalidConfiguration=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.stagingDirectory)". And then an Azure App Service Deploy task that tries to deploy that zip.

Comment: @CrashGordon What's the result if you change the arguments to: /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Same result, Eddie.

Comment: Can you queue the build with "system.debug" variable set to true and then share the entire build logs?